# Group selecting objects in 3D

Tags: selection-tools

[image: example]

Hi,

I need some help in mass selecting specific parts of a composite object.For example, If I use "B" or "C" to select the brown sphere on one face, it also selects the ones on the diametrically opposite face because they are in the field of the selection in 3D.

Is there any was to select the spheres on just one face of this object?

Thanks in advance!

Best

Comment: *Shift L > (Select linked) Materials* combined with B (box select) and MMB to deselect may help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all the object of a same material, then it's simple:
First select an object of the desired material, then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> → Select Linked Materials.

If it select too much compared to your needs, you can still deselect afterwards by using the border select tool wich <kbd>B</kbd> or the circle select with <kbd>C</kbd>.

If you're gonna need to select those specific objects often, it might be a good idea to turn them into a collection (or a "group if you're using Blender 2.7 and older). So that you can simply select those groups from the outliner.

Select your objects and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. (For now this is buged in 2.8: the created collection isn't displayed in the outliner. That bug should be fixed in the future though.)
In 2.8, you can also open the "Move to collection" dialog by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>, hit "New collection", give a name to the collection and validate your choice by pressing <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. But it's a bit longer (but it's not bugged)